# VBA Excel insert-match function from other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, insert, match

I am trying implement index match function in for loop . I want to copy value from other workbook to active cell workbook.

here is code that i write:

```
Sub Amazon_Index()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Partner As Worksheet
Dim AcWS As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End With


Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Adis\Desktop\Amazon narudžbe\Partner lista\partner.xlsx")
Set Partner = WB.Sheets("lista")



For i = 2 To LastRow
  ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 19) = _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Partner").Range("A1:E100"), _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18), _
       Sheets("Partner").Range("B1:B100"), 0), 5)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the above code? Are you sure that **for all cases** `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18)` returns something and not erroring?

Comment: @FaneDuru i tried this solution but still get error now on this line : where is mtch . in excel i use this funkction : =INDEX('parnter lista amazon.xlsx'!$A$1:$B$100;MATCH(R2;'parnter lista amazon.xlsx'!$B$1:$B$100;0);1)

Comment: i think that active sheet is this Partner sheet so it does not look to my activesheet with cell R2 (i,18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approach but it works.

Sub Insert_Index()
'
' Insert_Index Macro
'
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End With

```
Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX([partner.xlsx]lista!R1C1:R70C5,MATCH(RC[-1],[partner.xlsx]lista!R1C2:R70C2,0),1)"
  Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX([partner.xlsx]lista!R1C1:R70C5,MATCH(RC[-2],[partner.xlsx]lista!R1C2:R70C2,0),5)"
    Range("S2:T2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:T" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Please, try replacing of:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
  ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 19) = _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Partner").Range("A1:E100"), _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18), _
       Sheets("Partner").Range("B1:B100"), 0), 5)
Next
```

with:

```
dim mtch
For i = 2 To LastRow
  mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18).value , _
         Sheets("Partner").Range("B1:B100"), 0)
  If not IsError(mtch) then
     ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 19) = _
     Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Partner").Range("A1:E100"), mtch, 5)
   End If                        
Next
```

If `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...` does not find a match, it raises an error...

Comment: Note to OP: there's no need to use `Index` here: `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 19).Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("E1:E100").Cells(mtch).Value`.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, being a range with a single column, it can be returned in this way. I only tried adapting its code in a way to work in case of no any match for some cases. I don't even know for sure if his specific situation does not involve a match for any case... I've just assumed that is improbable... :)

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine (upvoted)! I was just pointing out to OP that sometimes there's no need to use `WorksheetFunction`. Congratulations on the gold VBA badge, almost there for the Excel one!

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! Does Excel one means more than 25k? My target was 20K and from that limit I tried answering only challenging questions, or some simple only ones only in case I am bored and no something really interesting on the 'market'... :)

Comment: I meant the Excel gold badge - looks like you're almost there.